# How can I programmatically find Spark version in an executor node?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a method (that will be ran through an executor) that will return the Spark version as a string. I know that I can find the Spark version with the following code:

```
SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate().version (even on executor)
```

But, when I'm running tests (tests in Apache Spark source code, were written before mine), some tests fail with the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkSession should only be created and accessed on the driver.

So, I understand that I can't use SparkSession. Therefore my question is, is there any other way to find Spark version in an executor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by importing SPARK_VERSION directly:

```
import org.apache.spark.SPARK_VERSION
```

There was also an option to transfer version with configuration that was already in my class.